# Estimation of the mean and the the variance in Shapiro-Wilk test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, estimation

I have started to learn about the non-parametric tests recently. And in my textbook, the introduction to the Shapiro-Wilk test ( a test of normality) is as below:

" ...
Let $X_1,...,X_n$ be i.i.d. We note $\mu =\mathbb{E}[X_i]$ and $\sigma ^2 = Var(X_i)$. Suppose that the distribution of $Y_i=\dfrac{X_i-\mu}{\sigma}$ is symmetry. We note $(X_{(1)},...,X_{(n)})$ the ordered sample of $X_i$, which means that $X_{(1)}\le...\le X_{(n)}$. And $(Y_{(1)},...,Y_{(n)})$ the ordered sample of $Y_i$. We have: 
$$Y_{(i)}=\dfrac{X_{(i)}-\mu}{\sigma}$$
For $i,j \in {1,...,n}$, we note $\alpha _ i=\mathbb{E}[Y_{(i)}]$ and $B_{i,j}=Cov(Y_{(i)},Y_{(j)})$. We have:
$$X_{(i)}=\mu +\alpha_i \sigma+\epsilon_i,$$
with $\mathbb{E[\epsilon_i]}=0$. The $\epsilon_i$ are not independent.

We note $A$ the matrix of size $(n,2)$ defined by $A=(1_n,\alpha)$ where $1_n=(1,...,1)'$ and $\alpha=(\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n)'$. We also note $X_{(.)}=(X_{(1)},...,X_{(n)})'$ and $\epsilon=(\epsilon_1,...,\epsilon_n)'$. We have: 
$$X_{(.)}=A\cdot \begin{pmatrix} \mu\\ \sigma \end{pmatrix}+\epsilon$$
The estimation of $(\mu,\sigma)$ is obtained by minimizing the following criteria: $$\bigg(X_{(.)}-A\cdot \begin{pmatrix} \mu\\ \sigma \end{pmatrix}\bigg)'B^{-1}\bigg(X_{(.)}-A\cdot \begin{pmatrix} \mu\\ \sigma \end{pmatrix}\bigg)$$
..."

I have some following issues that I do not understand:

Firstly, by the linearity of the expectation, we should have $\alpha_i=\mathbb{E}[Y_{(i)}]=\dfrac{\mathbb{E}[X_{(i)}]-\mu}{\sigma}=0$. Is it right? Further more, I do not understand why the $\epsilon_i$ are not independent. Since the $X_i$ are i.i.d and the $\epsilon_i$ depends only on $X_{(i)}$, the $\epsilon_i$ must be independent, I do believe.

Secondly, I think we would like to minimize the $||\epsilon||_2$. Thus the criteria we should consider is $$\bigg(X_{(.)}-A\cdot \begin{pmatrix} \mu\\ \sigma \end{pmatrix}\bigg)'\bigg(X_{(.)}-A\cdot \begin{pmatrix} \mu\\ \sigma \end{pmatrix}\bigg)$$

What is the factor $B^{-1}$ in the criteria used for? And if the $X_i$ are i.i.d, the $Y_i$ are also i.i.d and the matrix $B$ must be diagonal. Is this true?

Comment: How did you obtain $\mathbb{E}[X_{(i)}]=\mu$?  Please bear in mind that the subscripts refer to the data *in order.*  For instance, $X_{(1)}$ is (by definition) the smallest in the sample and therefore is unlikely to equal or exceed $\mu.$

Comment: But $\mu=\mathbb{E}[X_{i}]$ for all $i$, no? Can't we infer that $\mathbb{E}[X_{(1)}]=\mu$ ?

Comment: No.  To make this plainly obvious, consider the case of (say) $n=10^6$: what do you think the expectation of the smallest of a million independent values is going to be?  It's not going to be anywhere near $\mu$!  Once you truly understand this intuitive point, perhaps the formal mathematics will become clear.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and your help :)) . But to be honest, I cannot understand. For example, the $X_1,...,X_n$ (for any n) have the normal distribution (say) $N(0,1)$. So for all $i$, $X_i \sim N(0,1)$ and we always have $\mathbb{E}[X_{i}]=0$, even though for the smallest $X_i$, no?

Comment: Think of it like this: from one sample to another, the smallest of the $X_i$ is a *different one* of the data: it's not a fixed component of the vector $(X_1,X_2,\ldots, X_n).$  If that still doesn't make sense, then I invite you to conduct a small quick simulation.  Here is a picture of the empirical distribution of $X_{(1)}$  created in `R` (for $n=50$ with 10,000 realizations): `for (n in 50) hist(apply(matrix(rnorm(n*1e4), n), 2, min))`